# Exiting pygame window on click

Tags: python, events, click, pygame, exit

Making my first post here (or frankly any forum), but I was wondering why I can't exit on when the window's exit button [x] has been pressed. I have tried:

```
#print "Exit value ", pygame.QUIT
for et in pygame.event.get():
    #print "Event type ", et.type
    if et.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if (et.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE) or (et.type == pygame.QUIT):
                    print "In Here"
                    return True;
pygame.event.pump()# not quite sure why we do this
return False;
```

I've found out pygame.QUIT prints a value of 12, as I run the program an event type prints '12' when I click the [x]. The "In here" string never print on these occasions. The program exits properly when the return is true (when I press ESC on keyboard). I've looked at a few related issues: So

I'm not running on IDLE, I'm running it on:

Eclipse Juno Service Release 1.
Python 2.7.3 with the latest version of pygame for 2.7 (as of 3/4/13).
Windows 7 & 8 and Ubuntu 12.04LTS (same result besides the no soundcard error in Ubuntu)

I have run in Windows 7 by double clicking the .py file that runs the program and still does not exit on [x]. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your event loop,

```
#print "Exit value ", pygame.QUIT
for et in pygame.event.get():
    #print "Event type ", et.type
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------#
    if et.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if (et.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE) or (et.type == pygame.QUIT):
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------#
                    print "In Here"
                    return True;
pygame.event.pump()  # not quite sure why we do this
return False;
```

**The Problem** (between the 2 `#------------#`)
Let's analyse that part:

1. If the if-block is entered, `et.type == KEYDOWN`
2. And your check for `QUIT` is in `if et.type == KEYDOWN`.
3. Since `et.type` is `KEYDOWN`, it can't be `QUIT`..
4. So, You Are not checking for `et.type == QUIT`,
   So, your window simply won't exit, even if you click the 'X'.

**What to do?**
Pull your `QUIT` out of `KEYDOWN`'s conditional, something like:

```
done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                done = True
                break # break out of the for loop
        elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
            break # break out of the for loop
    if done:
        break # to break out of the while loop

    # your game stuff
```

Note:

- You don't need a `;` after those return statements
- Always check `event.type` in different if-elif blocks, like

  ```
  if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
       #...
  elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
       #...
  ```
- You don't need `pygame.event.pump()` there, see [Here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump)

Answer (score 2):

Your main loop should look like this

```
done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE: done = True
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            done = True

    # draw etc...
    pygame.display.update()
```

Then, if you toggle 'done' anywhere, it will nicely quit.